# Is it possible to register commands to a breakpoint from within an external file in GDB?

Tags: gdb

GDB allows registering a set of commands to a specific breakpoint via `commands NUM` syntax. I need to register the set of commands for a specific breakpoint via an external file, by using a syntax something like the following:

```
commands ./main.c:18
silent
print buffer[0]
cont
end

commands ./io.c:29
silent
printf "Hello world %i\n", myvar1
cont
end
```

The `commands path/to/file:XX` syntax is made up by me. Because the `NUM` in `commands NUM` syntax requires exactly the breakpoint's runtime ID number (assigned by GDB), I can not use a deterministic syntax for that purpose.

I'm currently registering breakpoints via a text file with such a content:

```
break ./main.c:18
break ./io.c:29
```

and then issuing `source breakpoints.txt` command inside GDB. It seems that there is no way to register `commands` at the same time while registering a breakpoint:

> (gdb) help break
> Set breakpoint at specified line or function.
> break [PROBE_MODIFIER] [LOCATION] [thread THREADNUM] [if CONDITION]
> PROBE_MODIFIER shall be present if the command is to be placed in a
> probe point.  Accepted values are `-probe' (for a generic, automatically guessed probe type),` -probe-stap' (for a SystemTap probe) or
> `-probe-dtrace' (for a DTrace probe).
> LOCATION may be a line number, function name, or "*" and an address.
> If a line number is specified, break at start of code for that line.
> If a function is specified, break at start of code for that function.
> If an address is specified, break at that exact address.
> With no LOCATION, uses current execution address of the selected
> stack frame.  This is useful for breaking on return to a stack frame.
>
> THREADNUM is the number from "info threads".
> CONDITION is a boolean expression.
>
> Multiple breakpoints at one place are permitted, and useful if their
> conditions are different.

## Question

1. Is there any easy way to set some predetermined commands for a predetermined breakpoint from within a file?
2. If not, is there any equivalent way to pass the `(gdb) info breakpoints` output to a file or a program while [`pipe`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Shell-Commands.html) is not available in GDB (version 5.3)? Currently I'm trying a workaround by using [`logging`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html#Logging-Output) feature for that purpose:

```
    set logging file /tmp/breakpoints
    set logging on
    info breakpoints 
    set logging off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any easy way to set some predetermined commands for a predetermined breakpoint from within a file?

Yes: if you use `commands` *without* `NUM`, the commands will apply to the last breakpoint set. So you want something like:

```
break main.c:18
commands
silent
print buffer[0]
cont
end
```